# Python3.5.1 definitions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a script (macro?) in Python 3.5.1 (on Windows) that will read from 1 file and type it into another.  The second program is a emulator that does not allow copy & paste or the typewrite function in pyautogui. I am able to write the script to pull the info per line and enter it using ctypes. I need the program to determine the length of the product, based of that, preform actions bases on what character is in what position. That works so far but i would have to repeat the section of code for ever product. My question is, is it possible to define the following so i don't have to enter or is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
if len(Product) == 2:
    if Product[0] == '1':
        PressKey (0x31)
    if Product[0] == '2':
        PressKey (0x32)
    if Product[0] ==  '3':
        PressKey (0x33)
```

I have tried a ton of variations of the following:

```
def Product(line):
     if len(line) == 2:
        if Product[0] == '1':
            PressKey (0x31)
        if Product[0] == '2':
            PressKey (0x32)
        if Product[0] ==  '3':
            PressKey (0x33)
Product(#this is where it would call the line from the file)
```

any ideas on how to make this work? Or a better way to go about this? It's a trial and error thing but this has gotten me stumped...

Comment: This seems to be just `PressKey(0x30 + int(Product[0]))`.

Answer (score 0):

From the pattern you've shown which maps `Product[0]` to a certain key press, it appears that you want to just add `Product[0]` into `0x30`. That is,

```
def Product(line):
    if len(line) == 2:
        PressKey(0x30 + int(line[0]))
```